# Javascript validation not performing as exepected

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a problem with my JS validation code. When I submit the form and there are errors, the form shouldn't go any further. But yet, the code doesn't stop, instead it carries on to the next line, which shows a successful message although there are still errors.

And I've clearly written that if, for example the field is empty, then `return false`...

Why does the code carry on to the next line, even though there's `return false`?

Press `submit` and you'll see what I mean.

JS:

```
(function(window, $) {

    var Namespace = (function(Namespace) {

        Namespace = {

            // Main
            run : function() {
                this.validate.run('form');
            },              

            // Validation
            validate : {

                // error message span
                messageBox : '<span class="message" />',

                // add any field here
                fields : {
                    nameField : $('#contact-name'),
                    emailField : $('#contact-email'),
                    phoneField : $('#contact-phone')
                },

                // run validation
                run : function(formName) {

                    $(formName).on('submit', $.proxy(this.validateField, this));
                },

                validateField : function() {
                    for (var field in this.fields) {
                        if (this.fields.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                            this.checkField(this.fields[field]);
                        }
                    }

                    $('#general-message-section').text('Form successfully sent, thank you!');
                    return false;
                },

                checkField : function(field) {

                    var messageBox = $(this.messageBox);

                    field.closest('li').find('.message').remove();

                    if (field.hasClass('required')) {
                        if (!field.val()) {
                            messageBox.text('This field is empty!');
                            field.closest('li').append(messageBox);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (this.fields.emailField.val()) {
                        this.fields.emailField.closest('li').find('.message').remove();

                        if (!this.fields.emailField.val().match(this.regEx.email)) {
                            messageBox.text('Only email format accepted!');
                            this.fields.emailField.closest('li').append(messageBox);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (this.fields.phoneField.val()) {
                        this.fields.phoneField.closest('li').find('.message').remove();

                        if (!this.fields.phoneField.val().match(this.regEx.numbers)) {
                            messageBox.text('Only numbers are accepted!');
                            this.fields.phoneField.closest('li').append(messageBox);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                },

                regEx : {
                    email : /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/,
                    numbers : /^[0-9]+$/
                }
            }
        };

        return Namespace;

    }(Namespace || {}));

    // make global
    window.Namespace = Namespace;

}(window, jQuery));

// run it...
Namespace.run();
```

HTML:

```
<p id="general-message-section"></p>
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="#">
    <fieldset>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="contact-name">Contact name *:</label>
                <input type="text" id="contact-name" tabindex="1" class="required" autofocus />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="contact-email">Contact email address *:</label>
                <input type="text" id="contact-email" tabindex="2" class="required" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="contact-phone">Contact phone number:</label>
                <input type="text" id="contact-phone" tabindex="3" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" tabindex="4" value="Submit" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Its easier (for others) if you post the relevant code in the question itself!

Comment: as a point of future reference, please also include a copy paste of your code in your question.

Comment: your return false is after your message, so naturally they will execute in order. A return inside another function will not break the parent function. You have to check the result of the inner function too and return it if it's false.

Comment: I've now posted the code in here. I thought it would be easier, because I thought the code would be too long for you guys... Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check all required fields and set `valid` to false if any `checkField()` return false but wont break the For loop, it will check if valid is false after the loop and break:

```
        validateField : function() {
            var valid = true;
            for (var field in this.fields) {
                if (this.fields.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                    if(this.checkField(this.fields[field]) === false) valid = false;
                }
            }
            if(!valid) return false;

            $('#general-message-section').text('Form successfully sent, thank you!');
        }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/F7Fh6/)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are missing a check in your validation logic. Your code:

```
validateField : function() {
    for (var field in this.fields) {
        if (this.fields.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
            this.checkField(this.fields[field]);
        }
    }

    $('#general-message-section').text('Form successfully sent, thank you!');
    return false;
},
```

Does call `checkField` but doesn't check its result (which can be false). I guess you could have something like:

```
validateField : function() {
    for (var field in this.fields) {
        if (this.fields.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
            if(!this.checkField(this.fields[field])) {
                alert("There are errors!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    $('#general-message-section').text('Form successfully sent, thank you!');
    return false;
},
```

And of course `return true;` in `checkField` if it's correct (at the end), or else it won't work either.

Comment: Thanks @Meta, but only 1 field is being shown an error though. I want each field to show an error message beside it at the same time, since they're all empty at the same time. How can I do that?

Comment: You could have a boolean initialized to `true` in your `validateField` function, and then set it to `false` whenever a call to `checkField` is false. After the loop check that boolean and show the message you need (error or success). For it to work, you need `checkField` to return `true` if everything was alright. Hope it helps!

Comment: you don't need to return true in checkField you can instead check if the checkField is equal to fasle, check my answer.

Comment: @razzak yeah, now you edited it it's correct ^^ @Shaoz just for the record, remember it's returning `undefined` if you don't return `true` yourself, and checking for `!(checkField...)` will lead to errors since `!undefined` is `true`